# Securing RESTEasy based RESTFul service using HTTP Header Credentials

Tags: java, resteasy, restful-authentication

I am trying to develop a RESTFul service which is written using RESTEasy. When I tried to restrict the service access using RESTEasy Roles based authentication and HTTP Header based authentication credentials it didn't success due to the following.
The marked services correctly restricted based on the defined **@RolesAllowed** on the services. However, upon access attempts it throws a more generic exception ("HTTP 403 Forbidden") at the back-end. This is against my will as it throws the same exception even I passed the security credentials in the HTTP header.
When I tried to address this by introducing a **ContainerRequestFilter**, it never invoked.
Could anyone help me on this and point out what went wrong.

These are the implementation details

**Service Class**

```
<pre>
@Path("/user-service")
public class UserService {

    @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    @PUT
    @Path("/users/{userName}")
    public Response updateUser(@PathParam("userName") String userName, @Context Request req) {
        // Do processing stuff here

        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
}
</pre><br>
```

**SecurityIntercepter Class**

```
<pre> 
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class SecurityInterceptor implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        System.out.println("<SecurityInterceptor> Invoking SecurityInterceptor filter");

        ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoker = (ResourceMethodInvoker) requestContext
                .getProperty("org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker");
        Method method = methodInvoker.getMethod();

        // Do process HTTP Header and authorized based on the auth Token
    }
}
</pre>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.UserService</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had been resolved by changing the web.xml file.
It seems like I have added few unnecessary statement which eventually caused the filter invoke.
Please find below the correct configuration details.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```